# How to update `linkRef` in to `touched` state by function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-forms

In my app, I use the `linkRef` in form. some reasons I require to update the `linkRef` to `touched` state, when i do getting error by function. what is the correct way to do this?

template:

```
<div *ngIf="linkRef.errors && (linkRef.dirty || linkRef.touched)" class="error" >
```

method:

```
 addAdnlVasSelection(addVas, linkRef){

        console.log('linkRef', linkRef);

        if(!addVas.input || !linkRef.errors ){
            linkRef.tourched(true); //notworks 
            linkRef.tourched = true;  //notworks 
            return;
        }
}
```

what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that linkref has the form instance, try:

```
this.linkRef.markAsTouched()
```

Comment: Works fine. But still getting an error as `linkRef.markAsTouched is not a function` - what to do?

Comment: Could you add some more code, please? Or could you make a demo?